# Upper and lower limit for number of categories in ordinal data

Tags: ordinal-data, kendall-tau

I want to categorize a variable on ordinal scale and give them values of 0,1,2,3... etc. Are there any upper and lower limits for number of categories for it to be considered ordinal data. I want to use Kendall's tau test for its analysis later.

Ques 1. There are many examples with 4 and 5 categories but is it OK if there are 10 categories? Is there any upper limit for it.

Ques 2. Also, can 2 categories as (0, 1) or (1,2) be considered ordinal data and be eligible for Kendall's test or should this be analyzed by t-test or chi-square test only. Is 3 is the minimum of categories in ordinal data?

Comment: My personal upper limit for the number of categories I will accept in ordinal data is 4,929,900,037.  YMMV :-).

Comment: Ok!! For large number of categories, the linear methods should also work (e.g Pearson or Spearman correlation). What would you say is smallest number of ordered categories for such linear methods to be applicable?

Comment: Two.  But I can't conceive of any examples where declaring them to be ordinal achieves anything that a categorical procedure won't already accomplish.

Comment: So, effectively we do not need Kendall's test. We could use Spearman's correlation, Chi-square test or Mann-Whitney U test with ordinal data. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit on the number of items in an ordinal set, unless there's a limit in a particular functional implementation.

An ordinal set can have 2 members.  (short, tall  :: light, heavy). The order can matter - for example comparing less and more across variables.  Generally speaking the order of (true, false) wouldn't be meaningful.

Regarding Kendall's tau test, the formulas do not have any limitations or the number of categories.  I can't imaging an implementation complaining about 10.

Comment: The meaning of your second paragraph is obscure, because you seem to be asserting that order in binary categories does and does not matter.  Could you clarify that?  Where it does matter, *how* does it matter?

Comment: Generally speaking, the order doesn't matter.  I'm sure there could be some arranged application where it does.